# Slide div left to right timing

Tags: jquery, html, timer, fadein, slide

I'm trying to code a series of divs / word elements to slide in from the left of off the screen then fade out whilst then next one comes in off the screen after.  I'm looking to have it so it loops and doesn't require a click action to load.  Is my code correct in doing this process? I'm still learning but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $("#design").animate({left: "250"}, 1000, function() {
        $("#brand").animate({left: "250"}, 1000, function() {
    });
});

setTimeout(function(){
$("design").fadeOut("slow", function () {
$("design").remove();
});

}, 1000);
```

CSS

```
   #design {
width: 5%;
padding: 4px;
top: 75%;
right: 31.8%;
right: -200px;
background-color: #ffff44;
z-index: 0;
   }

  #brand {
width: 4%;
padding: 4px;
top: 43%;
right: -200px;
font-size: 1.4em;
background-color: #ffff44;
z-index: 0;
    }
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Ah I apologise. I wanted to know if any experienced people knew a solution to my code as its not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at sliders or tickers? Here is a slider that might do what your looking for. [bx slider](http://bxslider.com/)